# MVC3 MapRoute Ambiguous between Controller Name without area and the equal Area Name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, maproute

This Is My Controllers in root (Without Area):

- Home
- Members

And My Areas are:

+General

- Controller1
- Controller2

+Members

- Manage
- Member

So My `Login` Action is in Members Controller (in Root) before I Add Members Area every thing is fine, but know I receive 404 error for this url
 (http://MyProject.dev/members/login?ReturnUrl=%2f)

So How can I define a MapRoute to fix this problem?

**Update**

I try this one in Main `Global.asax`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
             "newLogMaproute",
             "members/login{*pathInfo}",
             new { area = "", controller = "Members", action = "Login"}
        );
```

But there is an error: `A path segment that contains more than one section, such as a literal section or a parameter, cannot contain a catch-all parameter.`

And I try this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
             "newLogMaproute",
             "members/login/{*pathInfo}",
             new { area = "", controller = "Members", action = "Login"}
        );
```

but this one returned 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening here is the area registration is happening before your member route, so the area route is always taking precedence.

I fixed this in a test app by creating the following in the Global.asax:

```
  public static void RegisterPreAreaRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
  {
     routes.MapRoute(
     "Members", // Route name
     "members/login", // URL with parameters
     new { controller = "members", action = "login" } // Parameter defaults
   );
  }
```

Then in the Application_Start making sure this route gets mapped *before* the areas get registered:

```
  protected void Application_Start()
  {
     RegisterPreAreaRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
     AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
     RegisterGlobalFilters( GlobalFilters.Filters );
     RegisterRoutes( RouteTable.Routes );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need define Custom Routes for your area.
This is not good. You will probably have problems after. 
The best is not to create an ambiguity.

Don't forget of define the namespaces in rotes configuration with new string[]:

```
   routes.MapRoute(
     "Members", // Route name
     "members/login", // URL with parameters
     new { }, // Parameter defaults
     new[] { "WebApp.Controllers" } // Namespaces for find 
   );
```